# Localization of Windows Desktop app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am starting a small project in C#/WPF writing a Windows desktop application. However, searching for information on how to localize the app seems a lot more challenging. Most of the information I find is very abstract and takes more about planning than actual code and how to do it.

Since I am writing a small application, I just need a very simple explained "how to" translate text, and good practices to consider.

Anyone have any experience that can share some resources or some pointers in the right direction?

Comment: Localization is not simple, that is why you are finding complex abstract explanations.  If you are just trying to translate the application to the local language, search for that rather than `Localization` as the latter is far more complex than simple text translation.

Comment: Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718.aspx), though I dislike satellite concept bundled with using tools and export/import (which in WPF still same bad as it was in winforms).

Answer (score 0):

I always recommend the WPF Localize extension: http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/

When using that you can do something like:

```
<Button Content="{lex:Loc Test}" />
```

and the Content of the button is pulled from the resources.

Once set up it is very easy to use and a good introduction to it can be found [HERE](http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/documentation).

Answer (score 0):

Full on localization is so complex that one might argue to have an entirely separate UI by culture. Everything is different, dates, currency, text, layout, and even some colors or images would be a mistake in some cultures.

If it is just a small app and all you want to do is change the text based on culture here is a very simple example:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/299436/WPF-Localization-for-Dummies

Answer (score 0):

Another simple but elegant way to localize applications can be found here:
http://wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html
It's based on markup extensions.